# Material-ui/pickers: When InputAdornmentProps property with position start added to KeyboardDatePicker an unwanted margin appears

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, datepicker, material-ui

I have this component from material-ui/pickers:

```
<KeyboardDatePicker
   value={selectedDate}
   onChange={(_, newValue) => handleClick(newValue)}
   labelFunc={renderLabel}
   disableToolbar
   variant='inline'
   inputVariant='filled'
   format='YYYYMMDD'
   allowKeyboardControl
   autoOk
   inputProps={{
     'data-testid': `input-${name}`
   }}
   InputAdornmentProps={{ position: 'start' }}
 />
```

This property is causing the problem.
Without it the style is fine an the icon is centered vertically in the component. When I try to move the icon to the beginning of the component there appears an extra style:

```
    .MuiInputAdornment-filled.MuiInputAdornment-positionStart:not(.MuiInputAdornment-hiddenLabel) {
   margin-top: 16px;
}
```

That causes icon to be off-center.
This is what it looks like without InputAdornmentProps:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxGaM.png

And with it:
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHA53.png

What could be causing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this as below, and refer to [here](https://material-ui.com/api/input-adornment/) for more details.

```
InputAdornmentProps={{ position: 'start', variant: 'standard' }}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, what solved this issue was specify the KeyboardButtonProp - edge: "start. See here https://material-ui.com/api/icon-button/